# console.log does not work on Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a website on Wordpress,

**I've this function in PHP :**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myfunction', 'myfunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myfunction', 'myfunction' );
function myfunction() {

    require_once(ABSPATH."private/classes/utils.class.php");

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $listeLocalisation=Utils::listeLocalisation($_POST['localisation']);

    echo json_encode($listeLocalisation);
}
```

**In my JS file :**

```
jQuery(".localisation").change(function () {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { action: "myfunction"},
    url: adminAjax,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('TEST');
    }
  });
});
```

When I'm inspecting my console, I've receive the good data but my console.log() does not work .. nothing is displayed.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try first with `console.error()` and see if something changes. In many browsers by default the console is set to display only the errors. Also you can try to check your logging settings in the sidebar on the left side of the console, if it is not open you can show it by clicking "Show console sidebar" icon.

Comment: how do you confirm execution goes into `success` callback. Always use `error` to catch failed requests.

Answer (score -1):

JS is a real pain when you have to debug, but maybe try the followings:

1. Add this after the success:

```
error: function(){
   console.log("Some message to display when the error happens");
}
```

and see what happens. If you see the error message in the console, then there's a problem with your ajax request.

2. Disable cache in your browser, delete cookies and restart your browser.
3. Sometimes the same thing happens to me and if I'm 100% sure I've made no mistake, then... well... it sound unlogical and silly, but delete your whole ajax code and type down (or copy-paste) the same thing again. I know, I know, but sometimes it works for me.